# Prove that the minimum number of cycles is $m-n+1$

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

The question I have is:

Prove that the minimum number of cycles is $m-n+1$ in a connected graph. Where one cycle is a path that starts that begins and ends at the same vertex. Where $m$ is edges and $n$ is the vertices.

I have no idea where to start. A few hints would be appreciated. Please do not provide me with the answer.

Comment: The statement is not phrased in the best way. You want to prove that the number of cycles is at least $m-n+1$, and this is what's given in the answers. The function for the minimal number of cycles grows faster if $m$ is big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider a spanning tree of the graph. What happens when you add edges?

Let me first define what a tree is formally: A **tree** is a *connected* graph which contains *no cycles*. A **leaf** is a vertex of the tree which has degree $1$.

There are quite a few definitions which are equivalent, I shall choose one of the simplest and the one most suited for our application here.

Here are a few things which you will need to prove. These are not very long, if you have a proof which is very complicated then you've probably gone wrong somewhere. I've added hints in spoiler tags. Perhaps one thing I should mention. Do not let the abstract terms and definitions bog you down; a tree is *exactly* what you think it is (no, not the things outside). Your intuition will serve you well, you only need to take a bit of care to convert your intuition properly into a proof.

**1.** Every tree has at least two leaves.

> **Hint**: Consider "walking" through the tree. Can we continue this process indefinitely? Where must we end up?

**2.** A tree on $n$ vertices has precisely $n-1$ edges.

> **Hint**: Use the above fact and induction.

**3.** Adding any edge to a tree will create a cycle.

> **Hint**: If you add an edge $(u,\ v)$ then can you find two different paths now from $u$ to $v$?

Now a **spanning tree** is a connected, cycle-less subgraph of a connected graph which contains every vertex.

**4.** Every connected graph has a spanning tree.

> **Hint**: Induct on the number of edges.

These should be enough to provide a very rigorous proof of your fact.

Comment: Can you please provide an example, we haven't learned "spanning tree" yet.

Comment: Hmm. The concept is rather simple if you're willing to accept the fact that a spanning tree actually exists (which does require proof). Basically it's a connected sub-graph of the original graph which is cycle-less and contains every vertex. Have you learned about the numerous equivalent properties which characterize a tree?

Comment: If you want, I can provide a proof that every connected graph has a spanning tree. But I think it's a good exercise to try yourself.

Comment: We haven't learned the equivalent properties yet and an example of a spanning tree would be great.

Comment: Your teacher told you to prove this without introducing trees at all? What do you have to work with? As for examples, you can find quite a few just by googling spanning tree. Take a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpanningTree.html) for example.

Comment: Our teacher didn't teach us spanning trees but gave a general understanding for graphs.

Comment: I don't think I can come up with a very elementary proof which avoids spanning trees. What I can do for you is to provide a guide (i.e. a list of results for you to prove which will lead you to a solution). Would that be OK? I will of course see you through to the end.

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: What if G was disconnected? Can you give some clue how to proceed?

Comment: @slazer Nothing really changes. You would apply the bound to each connected component of the disconnected graph. The end result would be that the minimum number of cycles is $m-n+c$, where $c$ is the number of connected components.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an argument that does not require any results about trees.

Suppose we start with an $n$-vertex graph that has no edges, and add $m$ edges to it, one at a time.

When does adding an edge create a cycle? A cycle using edge $vw$ in a graph $G$ consists of following a path from $w$ to $v$ not using the edge, and then taking the edge $vw$ to return to the start. So a new cycle is created whenever there was a path already between the endpoints of the new edge.

Therefore each new edge can do one of two things:

1. Connect two vertices that were not connected before. This reduces the number of connected components by $1$, but creates no new cycles.
2. Connect two vertices that *were* connected before. This creates at least one more cycle.

Since we have $n$ connected components initially, option 1 can happen at most $n-1$ times, so option 2 must happen at least $m-(n-1)$ times, creating at least $m-n+1$ cycles.

This minimum value can be achieved for relatively small $n$; for example, the [friendship graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph) has $2n+1$ vertices, $3n$ edges, and exactly $n = 3n - (2n+1) + 1$ cycles. But eventually, we get more cycles than this; for example, with $\binom n2$ edges, our only option is the complete graph, which has many more than $\binom n2 - n + 1$ cycles: it has $\binom n3$ cycles of length $3$ alone.

Comment: (Yes, this is a very old question, but I figured that since it came up recently, it was worth adding this very simple argument as an answer.)

Comment: And what if graph is connected, so we do not have first case? Then, minimum number of edges is $n-1$ right? So adding any of remaining $m-(n-1)$ will create a cycle?

Comment: We started from the empty graph, which has $0$ edges. (You could *also* start with a tree and then use the fact that an $n$-vertex tree has $n-1$ edges, but then you're writing a different proof from mine.)

Comment: So, if start with the tree that has $n-1$ edges then if given $m$ is equal to $n-1$ we dont have the cycle. Else, we remove remaining $m-n+1$ edges(those edges are on cycles) and then add them back one by one(because remaing $m-n+1$ edges are between vertices that are not neighbors), so we have $m-n+1$ cycles. Is this valid?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you learned what a tree is, you can do induction by $m$.

If $m=n-1$, then your graph is connected and satisfies the tree formula, so how many cycles are there.

The inductive step is easy: If you have a graph on $m+1$ edges, then $m+1>n+1$ thus your graph is not a tree, and hence must have a cycle. remove one edge from the cycle, use induction and add it back...

Comment: How do we know that adding one edge only adds one cycle?  I agree this shows that $m-n+1$ is a lower bound, but do we know it is attained?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.

**Claim:**$\;$G has at least $m-n+1$ cycles.

**Proof:**

Proceed by induction on $n$.

If $n=1$, the claim holds trivially since then $m=0$ and $m-n+1=0-1+1=0$.

For $n > 1$, let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, and assume the claim holds for all connected graphs with $n-1$ vertices.

Let $c$ be the number of cycles of $G$.

Our goal is to show that $c\ge m-n+1$.

Since $G$ is connected every vertex has degree at least $1$.

Suppose some vertex, $v$ say, has degree $1$.

Then $G-v$ has $n-1$ vertices, $m-1$ edges, and $c$ cycles, hence by the inductive hypothesis, we get $c\ge (m-1)-(n-1)+1=m-n+1$, and we're done.

Next assume every vertex has degree at least $2$.

Choose vertices $u,v$ of $G$ such that the distance $d(u,v)$ is largest.

Let $w$ be a vertex of $G$ other than $v$ and let $p$ be a path of least distance in $G$ from $u$ to $w$.

Then $v$ can't be a vertex of $p$ else $d(u,w) > d(u,v)$, contrary to the choice of $u,v$.

Thus the path $p$ in $G$ from $u$ to $w$ is also a path in $G-v$.

It follows that $G-v$ is connected.

Let $k=\deg(u)$.

Then $G-v$ has $n-1$ vertices and $m-k$ edges, hence by the inductive hypothesis, $G-v$ has at least $(m-k)-(n-1)+1=m-n-(k-2)$ cycles.

Of course any cycle of $G-v$ is also a cycle of $G$.

Let $w_1,...,w_k$ be the neighbors of $v$

Since $G-v$ is connected, for each pair $w_i,w_j$ where $1\le i < j\le k$, there is a path $p_{i,j}$ in $G-v$ from $w_i$ to $w_j$. If we augment the path $p_{i,j}$ by prepending the edge $vw_i$ and appending the edge $vw_j$, we get a cycle in $G$, and these cycles are distinct from the cycles of $G-v$, and disctinct from each other.

Thus there at least ${\large{\binom{k}{2}}}$ cycles of $G$ which are not cycles of $G-v$.

Since $k\ge 2$, it follows that ${\large{\binom{k}{2}}} \ge k-1$, hence
$$
c
\ge
{\small{\binom{k}{2}}}
+
\bigl(m-n-(k-2)\bigr)
\ge
(k-1)
+
\bigl(m-n-(k-2)\bigr)
=
m-n+1
$$
as was to be shown.

This completes the proof.