# A graph has 29 vertices and 41 edges. What is the minimum number of distinct cycles that this graph could have?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I am trying to solve this. However, it is not clear for me the best way to model the problem.

I was trying to start with a **star** graph, with 29 vertices, 28 edges and no cycle. Slowly, I would add an edge to build one cycle. Slowly, my star graph would approach to a wheel graph.

This is a picture of what I am calling a star graph.

[image]

Are start graphs turning to wheel graphs the best way to minimize cycles creation?

If yes, What am I doing wrong?
If no, how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't a wheel graph have a cycle already?

Comment: Are you forbidding edges from a node to itself?

Comment: @coffeemath, sorry, I was being imprecise. I tried to edit my post in order to make it clear.

Comment: @IskyMathews, the exercise does not mention anything about that.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225570/prove-that-the-minimum-number-of-cycles-is-m-n

Comment: @vadim123, thanks. I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a star graph is a good approach.  When you make the star you have $28$ arms and $13$ edges yet to place.  You can place the $13$ on disjoint pairs and argue that you have only made $13$ cycles.  The answers to the question vadim123 linked show this is a minimum so you are done.  Your approach works as long as the number of edges is less than $1+\frac 32(v-1)$ where $v$ is the number of vertices.