# Minimum number of cycles of a graph with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges and $c$ components.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges and $c$ components. Prove that $G$ contains at least $m-n+c$ cycles.
My Professor just forwards this question during lecture time but I don't have enough information how to tackle the proof of this statement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if $c$ is 1. What do you know for that case?

Comment: I read that it is $m-n+1$ but I don't  know how it came.

Comment: This post has an elegant solution!!! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225570/prove-that-the-minimum-number-of-cycles-is-m-n1 Take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Number of components in a forest $G$ is $|V(G)|$-$|E(G)|$, now, we have $c$ components and $n$ vertices, so the number of edges in the spanning trees of the graph is $n-c$. Now we have the remaining $m-(n-c)$ edges that are not part of the spanning tree. Whenever you add one of those edges to the spanning tree, you get a cycle. So you get at least $m-n+c$ cycles.