# Number of cycles in graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have to prove that minimum number of cycles in graph is $m-n+1$ where $m$ is number of edges, and $n$ number of vertices. My question is, can I prove this the same way as I proved the theorem that gives number of regions on which planar graph breaks the plane. The only different thing is that there was one unbounded area, which is not cycle in this case. And because of that we have +1and not +2 in formula.

Comment: I think this is good reasoning but you’d probably have clearly define an injection from the faces minus the outer face to the cycles, which is what you said. I mean you’d have to say there is an injection therefore the sizes of the two sets satisfy an inequality.

Comment: And also the Euler formula is true for planar graphs, not for any graph

Comment: Yeah, but, in fact that formula counts number of cycles in graph, because they are regions

Comment: No there are more cycles I think, take two triangles on nodes 1,2,3,4 sharing an edge (2,3). The resulting graph has 2 faces (ignoring the outer face) but 3 distinct cycles: 123,234,1243.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225570/prove-that-the-minimum-number-of-cycles-is-m-n1?rq=1) are some proofs of this formula.